# How to update the existing nodes attributes of a d3js tree, based on an input value from a search box?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with this d3js example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

In my case, the only difference is that the whole code is wrapped within a function that is being called externally. So consider that all the variables are defined within such function.

Then, still externally, I want to update the nodes attributes based on a search box that I created as following:

```
<div id="footer">
    <label for="search">search: </label>
    <input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="update(this.value)">
</div>
```

The box seems to be operational. I can type within it and each time I press a key it calls the following function that I created to get all the texts/labels from the existing nodes.

```
    function update(query) {
        var text = d3.select("svg")
            .selectAll('text')
            .style("font-weight", function (d) {
                console.log(d.name)
                if (d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1) { return "bold" } else { return "normal" }
            });
        }
```

Those texts should be updated based on the tag input of the query box et get bold. However, nothing changes. Did I call all my text elements in the right manner? Or maybe nothing gets updated because the whole script is initalized within a function that is being called externally?

Hope that was clear!

**EDIT - following Gerardo's first comment**

Thanks for your reply and highlight! I changed the name of the function. However in my case it is still unresponsive, unfortunately.

As mentioned I have a function that wraps everything, such as:

```
function updateDoc(json) {

        ...then all the code goes here...

      function updateName(query) {
        var text = d3.select("svg")
            .selectAll('text')
            .style("font-weight", function (d) {
                console.log(d.name)
                if (d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1){ 
            return "bold" } else { return "normal" }
            });
        }

    }
```

Most likely this is what causes the trouble. Any hint how to get this work? I do not want to call again the function updateDoc as it will recompute a bunch of things for nothing. I tried to place updateName outside updateDoc but does not work as well...

Answer (score 0):

Your function does work. The problem is simply its name: there is already a function named `update` in that code.

**Solution**: change its name. For instance, `updateName`:

```
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="updateName(this.value)">
```

Of course, don't forget to change the function's name in the script as well:

```
function updateName(query) {
    //etc...
```

Here is the bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/a81b92e7aadc14de65008aab0397944d/dd734b2cfcc9c2254ff6a5b803b531bc9900b449

Comment: Hi Gerardo, thanks a lot for your answer! I replied to you by editing the my post.

Comment: Here is how to call it inside an outer function: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/41197d2386b7e7652863c68e6e871d76/148383c4df9a782c94269447e4b856ef03c9d4a6

Comment: Sorry but for some reasons I can't get this work... It's frustrating when i see it working in your examples!
That's how i structured the entire code. updateLayers is called externally.
https://github.com/PaulPoinet/LayerStalker/blob/PaulPoinet-patch-2/index.html

Comment: Well, I can't help you more than this... I hope someone else write an answer that suits you.